# How can I improve my L2 skills in circumlocution?

Tags: circumlocution

I don't always know a word in my target language.  Some people seem like geniuses when it comes to speaking with a limited vocabulary, by substituting other words, or explaining the concept in an indirect, but concise manner.

If I find myself stumbling in these situations, how can I improve my ability to circumlocute?

Comment: Learning and knowing plenty of the easy and simple words might help, but that is just my experience.

Comment: Could you add a specific example of the situation you are referring to? I can't tell if "Some people" refers to another L2 person or an L1 person for that language. Vocabulary ability alone does not seem to be your primary factor, since you said "geniuses when it comes to speaking with a limited vocabulary".

Comment: This book comes to mind: https://xkcd.com/thing-explainer/

Comment: (and it's been translated into German, Dutch and Swedish, in case you're learning any of them)

Comment: Another way to improve this skill is to play the Taboo game with your friends: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo_(game)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get better at something is to do it. :)

---

Play a game with yourself. Think of a concept/word, and explain it (out loud) as best you can with the vocabulary you know (kinda like [Catch Phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_Phrase_(game))). *Circumlocute*. Alternatively, if you're in a social setting, with others who know your target language, you could actually *play* Catch Phrase.

Of course, solo Catch Phrase can get a little boring after a while. Here are a couple more ways to spice up your studying:

- Try describing what the word/concept is **not**.
- Add a time limit (the game Catch Phrase already has one).

Of course, regular old vocabulary study is going to help a bunch here, too.

---

Studying alone is not necessarily going to get you to where you need to be, speaking-wise. Converse with L2 speakers as much as possible. If you can become good friends with one, you'll feel more comfortable speaking with them, and you won't be as nervous about stumbling.

---

Keep practicing!